# Why can't I stack my Experience Scrolls?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have 9 [Experience Scrolls](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Experience_Scroll) but I can only stack them in 4, 4 and 1.

I can see the difference between one scroll and the rest, as 8 are 'Account Bound' and the odd one is 'Account Bound on Aquire', so I guess that's why they that one doesn't stack.

So why can't I stack the two 4 stacks into one 8 stack?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As written in the Notes on the wiki you linked there is currently a bug with them:

> There are three variants of this scroll. One variant is from achievement chests and the other two are from the first and second birthday. While they stack with themselves, they cannot stack with each other.

This sounds like what you are experiencing.

Comment: I wonder if they'll fix this. I've got this going on with some of the newer, daily login items not stacking with the older items earned through various means. It's annoying to take up twice the bank space for this.

Comment: @Seiyria That's actually a different problem, which is fixable. Some older items were showing up as "Account Bound on Acquire" while the newer versions of them are marked as "Account Bound". Putting the ones marked as "Account Bound on Acquire" in your inventory and switching maps should fix them, and allow them to be stacked with the others.

Comment: @Brian Thank god, I can now reclaim some bank space.

Comment: They've had this issue with a couple other items in the past.  I don't remember specific items, but it wasn't fixed for a while.  I found it easier to just use the item rather than wait for a fix.

Comment: I have this with Spinal Blade Shards.